# listen for django signals in JS

Tags: javascript, django, frontend, backend

Is there any way to implement a JS addEventListener that receives a signal from Django?

I have to upload multiple files, each one is processed individually sequentially, the idea is to notify as a list each time a document is finished processing.

My idea:

```
document.addEventListener('documento_extraido', function(event) {
  const nombreDocumento = event.detail.nombre_documento;
  console.log(`El documento ${nombreDocumento} ha sido procesado.`);
  // Aquí puedes agregar el código para mostrar la notificación de finalización de un documento en el frontend.
});
```